# PHP ldap_bind fails

Tags: php, ldap

I am having lots of trouble connecting to a LDAP server using PHPs ldap_bind function.
Here's my code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$ldap_ips = [
    '123.456.789.012'
];

$ldapuser = 'cn=Username,ou=Location_A,ou=Location_B,o=CompanyName';  
$ldappass = 'secret';

foreach ($ldap_ips as $ip) {
    testLdap($ip,$ldapuser,$ldappass);
}

function testLdap($ip,$ldapuser,$ldappass) {

    ldap_set_option(NULL, LDAP_OPT_DEBUG_LEVEL, 7);

    fsockopen($ip, 636) or die('failed at port 636');

    $ldapconn = ldap_connect("ldaps://" . $ip . ":636") or die("Could not connect to LDAP server.");

    if ($ldapconn) {

        // Trying to bind to ldap server. Fun stops here...
        $ldapbind = @ldap_bind($ldapconn, $ldapuser, $ldappass);

        var_dump(ldap_error($ldapconn)); // yields: Can't contact LDAP server

        // verify binding
        if ($ldapbind) {
            die('Success! However, this line has never been reached.');
        } 

        // all done? clean up
        ldap_close($ldapconn);

    }
}
?>
```

The url (`ldaps://123.456.789.012:636`) works fine on Softerra LDAP Browser 4.5 with the same credentials using the "simple" mechanism. Things I've tried are among others creating a file named `C:\OpenLDAP\sysconf\ldap.conf` containing text `TLS_REQCERT never` (this was mentioned multiple times on forums) to no avail.

Server specs: Windows Server 2012, IIS, PHP 7.0.20

Does anyone have a clue what might be going on or at least how to get PHP to return more information than "Can't contact LDAP server"? Thanks!

Comment: To prevent server certificate check you can put this line before initializing the connection : `putenv('LDAPTLS_REQCERT=never');`. But first have you tried to connect without ssl ? `$ldapconn = ldap_connect($ip, 389)`

Comment: It could also be related to network settings, do you run Softerra browser on the same machine as the one which is running the php script ? If not, have you checked you can reach your ldap server from the client machine ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can only use anonymous login at port 389 but I need to validate the user/password. Softerra browser indeed runs at the same machine. I will try "putenv('LDAPTLS_REQCERT=never')" first chance Monday, thanks.

Comment: It failed :( thanks for your input though